# Regex Help - Word Boundaries & excluding content within header tags

Tags: php, regex

I've got a special case where I am making phrase replacements and I need to keep my word boundaries and omit any actions from taking place on my content inside header tags (`<h1><h2><h3><h4><h5>`).

Here's what I got so far, and it is saying ignore phrases if they fall after a > or a -, which prevents URLS and Hyperlinks from being edited too.

```
preg_replace("/[^\>\.-]\b{$keywords}\b/i"," <a href='$url' target='$target'>$keywords</a>
```

So the regex needs to :

1. Honor word boundaries
2. Ignore phrases within header tags, and hyperlinks.
3. Treat -(dashes) as a boundary too, which \b does not seem to do.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the header tags with a lookahead.

```
/(?<!_)(?<!-)\b$keywords[$key]\b(?!(.*?)\<\/h\d>)/i
```

I tried to find a solution for text in alt and title tags using the look behind feature but could not get it to work without breaking the regex. It seems everytime I used a .+ or a (.*?) in the lookbehind it broke it.

Answer (score 1):

Advice:

- Realize that if you are trying to deal with arbitrary HTML tags and URLs, your criteria are simplistic and some special case *will* bite you some day.
- If you know that your keyword is alphabetic, you don't really need the `\b`s as such; try some variation of `[^-a-zA-Z\/>]` before and after the keyword. (I assume you meant to avoid slashes to guard against URLs -- and I think it's underscores (`_`) that `\b` doesn't see as boundaries, since they count as alphanumeric; using `\w` in the character class would give the same problem).